# Parsing values in pass-through query

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, ssms

In TSQL I'm using a pass-through query to select all the data from an Oracle database. It's a simple statement and it works fine. However, I realized I need to put some TRIM's in the pass-through query.

So, i went from this:

`Select *`

to this:

`Select TRIM(col1), col2`

Now, I cannot reference the columns in the pass-through. It seems like Select * allows you to refer to the columns by their names in Oracle, but once the columns are explicitly listed (like col2), I get an Invalid column name error.

Here is the simplified code in question. It says any reference of `SOURCE.col1` or `SOURCE.col2` are Invalid column names. (It's OK if I do a Select * in the pass-through though.)

```
 MERGE dbo.SqlServerTable AS TARGET
USING (
    SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(ORA_REP, '
        SELECT
            TRIM(col1),
            col2
        FROM OracleTable
        '
    )
) AS SOURCE
ON (TARGET.Foo = SOURCE.col1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        TARGET.Bar = SOURCE.col2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (
        Foo,
        Bar
    )
    VALUES (
        SOURCE.col1,
        SOURCE.col2
    )
;
```

Comment: Add aliases for the trimmed values?

Comment: Within the pass-through?

Comment: That would be the place to do it, if it's supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to alias the trimmed columns to the same names:

```
MERGE dbo.SqlServerTable AS TARGET
USING (
    SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(ORA_REP, '
        SELECT
            TRIM(col1) col1,
            TRIM(col2) col2
        FROM OracleTable
        '
    )
) AS SOURCE
ON (TARGET.Foo = SOURCE.col1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        TARGET.Bar = SOURCE.col2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (
        Foo,
        Bar
    )
    VALUES (
        SOURCE.col1,
        SOURCE.col2
    )
;
```

Comment: `col1 = TRIM(col1)` is invalid (standard) SQL and won't work in Oracle.

Comment: @russ : TRIM(col1) col1, TRIM(col2) col2

Comment: So aliasing the trimmed columns was the solution. However in Oracle syntax. So like: TRIM(col1) AS col1

Comment: Thanks, I'm a SQL guy: answer updated with Oracle syntax.